# Permanent Dropbox authorization PHP

Tags: php, authorization, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to develop a simple PHP application that would fetch files via Dropbox API.

Problem is the authorization, which user has to complete every time one tries to run the script (after the session expires).

I was wondering if there was a way of obtaining some permanent access token via which I could login the once-authorized user to my app.

Comment: I think people at Dropbox will be better able to answer this question about a feature of their API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The access token you receive from /oauth/access_token after the user authorizes the app is actually effectively permanent. (That is, they don't expire for a very long period of time.) So, you can store and reuse the access token for future calls for the user without having them re-process the OAuth authorization flow each time.

One thing to note though is that the user can revoke access tokens (e.g., via https://www.dropbox.com/account/applications ) so be careful to catch 401 errors. If you do get one, it means the access token is no longer valid, so you should throw it out and prompt the user to re-process the authorization flow if they want to use the integration again.

Comment: Great! I was just fiddling with what exactly is a query I should post to Dropbox to get the access_token once the user has authorized, and what is the query to submit the token next time?